# $('.parent .child') vs $('.parent').find('.child')

Tags: jquery

Is

```
$('parent child')
```

the same as

```
$('parent').find('child')
```

?

Edit: I do not ask about speed or performance. I want to know if they serve to do the same thing or if they do different things. If they are the same: why does it exist, for example, find () if it is longer to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) basically does the same thing. i.e., Traversing the descendants and getting matched elements.

**Descendant selector:**

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given
> ancestor.
>
> version added: 1.0jQuery( "ancestor descendant" ) ancestor: Any valid
> selector.
>
> descendant: A selector to filter the descendant elements.
>
> A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild,
> great-grandchild, and so on, of that element.

**find():**

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
> matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.
>
> version added: 1.0.find( selector )
>
> version added: 1.6.find( element )
>
> Given a jQuery object
> that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to
> search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and
> construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

The descendant selector is part of CSS selectors as well. So people who prefer writing in CSS combinators use descendant selector. And people who prefer readability use find()

Also from the find() documentation this is the difference i found between the two.

> **As of jQuery 1.6**, we can also filter the selection with a given ***jQuery
> collection or element***. With the same nested list as above, if we start
> with:
>
> `var allListElements = $( "li" );`
> And then pass this jQuery object to find:
>
> `$( "li.item-ii" ).find( allListElements );`
> This will return a jQuery collection which contains only the list elements that are descendants of item II.
>
> Similarly, an element may also be passed to find:
>
> `var item1 = $( "li.item-1" )[ 0 ];`
>
> `$( "li.item-ii" ).find(item1).css( "background-color", "red" );`
>
> The result of this call would be a red background on item 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think find `$(Parent).find(child)` is **faster** than `selector`.

Try this:
https://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again

Comment: i got `find` as the faster one when i tried the test on the link you mentioned

Comment: Testing in Chrome 65.0.3325 / Windows 8.1 0.0.0

Comment: oh sorry, i wanted to say `find` is faster.